# PHP, Script for retrieve information about resource, using the access log files

Tags: php, apache, class, logging, centos7

In order to not reinvent the wheel,

Someone knows a script (or class) that can read the log file from apache web service (access_log) and returns information about the times you have viewed a resource as a picture?

My system is Centos7 and Apache.

I thought to program a PHP script which stores the resource requests in bbdd, but why to increase the load with several insert queries per page? when can use the access_log

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Why PHP? From the command line:

```
grep /var/www/html/filename /var/log/http/access_log  | wc
```

Or use awstats or [similar](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software)

Comment: I need the information to perform processes within a web application, using PHP as I mentioned. Yes, I know AWSTATS (and it doesn't show statistics about concrete resources), but I need to work from PHP.
Thank you.